How do I correctly setup this testing scenario?
I have a method to process a loan request, it creates a new loan record from form inputs and uses it as a dependency for an API call.
I wrote a test for this method that includes faking an API call like this:
Http::fake(
    [
        config('services.dummy.url').'/v3/transfers' => Http::response(
            [
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'test message',
                'data' => [
                    'tx_ref' => $ref,
                    'meta' => [
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'loan_id' => $loan->id, //not available in test
                        'loanProvider_id' => $loanProvider->id,
                        'transfer_description' => 'Loan Disbursement',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            200
        ),
        config('services.dummy.url').'/v3/transactions/'.$ref.'/verify' => Http::response(
            [
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'test message',
                'meta' => [
                    'loan_id' => $loan->id, //not available in test
                ],
            ],
            200
        ),
    ]
);

The thing is that I need the loan record for the API call but it's not created within my test but within the method.
public function processLoanApplication(Request $request, User $user) {
    $loan = $user->loans()->create([...]);

    // API call
    $transferService->disburseLoan($loan);
}

This is the disburseLoan method:
public function disburseLoan(Loan $loan)
   {
        $data = $this->debitLoanProvider($loan);
        $result = $this->verifyTransfer($data['data']['tx_ref']);
        $this->useRecurringTransferVerificationResult($result);
   }

It calls the 2 APIs faked in the test and result is used for some housekeeping.
Depending on the result of the API calls, this $this->useRecurringTransferVerificationResult($result); calls other methods to create a transfer record, update the loan record, etc.
What's the correct way to set this test up?

I do not understand what is the issue. What does happen after disburseLoan runs? you really have no more lines of code? What are you asserting in your test

@matiaslauriti, After disburseLoan runs, the loan record is updated, among other things. Tests asserts that some events and notifications are dispatched as well database model values. The issue is that I need the loan id for Http::fake() but it only available during runtime, the record is created and then used in disburseLoan method.

Oh okay, I get it now. So I think you then want to either fake something else inside disburseLoan but not that part of the code, or you want to have total control of the database, so you always know what is the ID going to be (let's say you have no loans at all, so you know that creating one is going to have id = 1, so you do that on your fake API call), does it make sense? Could you add a bit more info about disburseLoan just to see if we can fake or mock something different?

@matiaslauriti, please see my update in response to your last comment.

I think that you may need to go further inside and try to fake something different, I cannot ask you to start adding all the methods into this question, but try finding which part can be stopped at and mocked, instead of mocking an API call

Yeah, I'm beginning to think that I'll just mock the disbursement in this test, exclude testing the API call and do that in a separate test.

That is another solution!

I ended up with this setup (with help from ChatGPT). This is the complete test.
test('that it processes a personal loan request and disbursement was successful', function () {
    // Arrange
    Storage::fake('public');
    $loanProvider = LoanProvider::factory()->create([
        'loan_type' => 'Personal Loan',
        'api_url' => 'dummy.providerurl',
        'api_secret' => 'dummyprovidersecret',
        'endpoints' => ['loanApplication' => '/loan/application']
    ]);
    $bank = Bank::factory()->create();
    $security = Security::factory()->create([
        'asset_category' => 'Equities',
        'market_price' => 100.0,
    ]);
    $user = User::factory()->verified()->identityVerified()->create();
    $user->billing->update([
        'bank_code' => $bank->bank_code,
        'account_number' => '1234567890'
    ]);
    $targetAmount = 15000000;
    $goalHorizon = today()->addYears(10);
    $horizonInYears = (int) (today()->diffInYears($goalHorizon));
    $recommendedSavings = $targetAmount / $horizonInYears;
    $totalProjectedSavings = $recommendedSavings * $horizonInYears;
    $totalProjectedReturns = $totalProjectedSavings * 15;
    $goal = $user->financialGoals()->create([
        'goal_name' => 'fake goal',
        'user_first_name' => $this->authUser->first_name, 
        'user_last_name' => $this->authUser->last_name,
        'target_amount' => $targetAmount,
        'goal_horizon' => $goalHorizon,
        'savings_type' => 'Periodic Savings',
        'recommended_savings' => $recommendedSavings,
        'total_projected_savings' => $totalProjectedSavings,
        'total_projected_returns' => $totalProjectedReturns,
        'renewal_date' => today(),
        'cumulative_cash_savings' => 750000,
        'set_for_implementation' => true,
        'fee_discount' => null,
        'verified_organisation_documents' => false,
        'implementation_status' => 'Active',
        'has_processed_share_transfer_forms' => false,
        'has_processed_dcs_opt_out' => false,
        'clearing_house_number' => null,
        'CSCS_settlement_status' => null,
        'setup_fee_paid_at' => null,
    ]);
    $goal->portfolios()->create([
        'investment_service_provider_id' => InvestmentServiceProvider::factory()->create()->id,
        'security_id' => $security->id,
        'security_asset_category' => $security->asset_category,
        'security_name' => $security->security_name,
        'equity_units' => 9000,
        'equity_unit_cost' => 50.0,
        'equity_total_cost' => 450000.0,
        'equity_market_price' => $security->market_price,
        'equity_market_value' => 900000.0,
    ]);
    $goal->setupSaving()->create([
        'goal_name' => $goal->goal_name,
        'amount' => 50000,
        'start_date' => today(),
        'savings_frequency' => 'Monthly',
    ]);
    $signature = UploadedFile::fake()->image('signature.jpg');
    $user->updateSignature($signature);
    $loanDocs = [
        'loanAgreement' => storage_path('/app/public/PLA'.$user->first_name.'.pdf'),
        'lienDocuments' => storage_path('/app/public/PLL'.$user->first_name.'.pdf')
    ];
    $request = [
        'amount' => 250000.00,
        'bank_code' => $bank->bank_code,
        'account_number' => '1234567890',
        'account_name' => $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name,
        'terms' => true,
        'loan_type' => 'Personal Loan'
    ];
    $this->partialMock(LoansController::class, function (MockInterface $mock) use ($loanDocs) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('processLoanDocumentation')
            ->withAnyArgs()
            ->once()
            ->andReturn($loanDocs);

        // Allow unexpected methods like getMiddleware
        $mock->makePartial();
    });
    $requiredData = [];
    Http::fake([
        $loanProvider->url.$loanProvider->endpoints['loanApplication'] => Http::response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'test message',
            'data' => [
                'status' => 'approved',
                'meta' => [
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'loanProvider_id' => $loanProvider->id,
                ],
            ],
            ], 200),
        config('services.nibss.url').'/v3/transfers' => function ($request) use ($user, $loanProvider,
            &$requiredData) {
            $requestBody = json_decode($request->body(), true);
            $ref = $requestBody['tx_ref'];
            $loanId = $requestBody['meta']['loan_id'];
            $amount = $requestBody['amount'];

            $requiredData['ref'] = $ref;
            $requiredData['loan_id'] = $loanId;
            $requiredData['amount'] = $amount;
            
            return Http::response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'test message',
            'data' => [
                'tx_ref' => $ref,
                'amount' => $amount,
                'meta' => [
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'loan_id' => $loanId,
                    'loanProvider_id' => $loanProvider->id,
                    'transfer_description' => 'Loan Disbursement',
                ],
            ],
            ], 200);
        },
        config('services.nibss.url').'/v3/transactions/*' => function () use (&$requiredData, $loanProvider, $user) {
            return Http::response([
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'test message',
                'data' => [
                    'status' => 'successful',
                    'amount' => $requiredData['amount'],
                    'tx_ref' => $requiredData['ref'],
                    'payment_type' => 'card',
                    'created_at' => now(),
                    'ip_address' => null,
                    'processor_response' => 'successful',
                    'card' => [
                        'reusable' => true,
                        'exp_year' => '2026',
                        'exp_month' => '07',
                        'token' => $loanProvider->auth_code,
                    ],
                    'meta' => [
                        'benefit_id' => null,
                        'goal_id' => null,
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'setupBenefit_id' => null,
                        'investment_service_provider_id' => null,
                        'loan_id' => $requiredData['loan_id'],
                        'loanProvider_id' => $loanProvider->id,
                        'reward_id' => null,
                        'providerAuth_id' => null,
                        'rewardProvider' => null,
                        'transfer_description' => 'Loan Disbursement',
                        'bill_type' => null,
                    ],
                ],
            ], 200);
        },
    ]);
    Notification::fake();
    Event::fake();

    // Act
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('loans.process-application', $user), $request);

    $loan = Loan::findOrFail($requiredData['loan_id']);

    // Assert
    $recorded = Http::recorded();
    expect($recorded[0][0]->url())->toBe($loanProvider->api_url.$loanProvider->endpoints['loanApplication']);
    expect($recorded[1][0]->url())->toBe(config('services.nibss.url').'/v3/transfers');
    expect($recorded[2][0]->url())->toBe(config('services.nibss.url').'/v3/transactions/'.$requiredData['ref'].'/verify');
    Http::assertSentCount(3);
    $this->assertDatabaseCount('loans', 1);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('loans', [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'loan_provider_id' => $loanProvider->id,
        'principal_amount' => $request['amount'],
        'loan_status' => 'running',
        'loan_start_date' => $loan->fresh()->loan_start_date,
    ]);
    $this->assertDatabaseCount('setup_loan_repayments', 1);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('setup_loan_repayments', [ "direct_repayment_start_date" => null]);
    $this->assertDatabaseCount('transfers', 1);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('transfers', [
        'model_id' => $loan->id,
        'amount' => $request['amount'],
        'transfer_status' => 'successful',
        'transfer_description' => 'Loan Disbursement',
    ]);
    Event::assertDispatched(SuccessfulTransfer::class);
    Notification::assertSentTo($loanProvider, SuccessfulLoanDisbursement::class);
    Notification::assertNotSentTo($loanProvider, LoanDocumentation::class);
    Notification::assertSentTo($user, LoanDisbursementNotification::class);
    Event::assertDispatched(PortfolioManagersNotice::class);
    $response->assertStatus(302);
    expect($loan->fresh()->loan_status)->toBe('running');
    expect($loan->fresh()->loan_start_date)->toEqual(today());
    $response->assertSessionHas('flash.banner', 'Your loan application was successful. You will receive funds shortly!');
    $response->assertSessionHas('flash.bannerStyle', 'success');
    $response->assertRedirectToRoute('loans.index');
    $this->followRedirects($response) // works but method isn't documented
        ->assertInertia(fn (AssertableInertia $page) => $page
            ->component('Loans/AllLoans')
    );
});


Could you edit the answer and share where is $isp and the other variable created? We need to see the complete order of execution to understand the solution

Hi @matiaslauriti, I've shared the  complete test code.
